# How to duplicate the content of a MiniDV to a DVD?

Tags: video, imovie, import

I'd like to save the content of some miniDV tapes to DVDs. I can use iMovie to do it, but iMovie creates a lot of video files and sort them by date. It will be a titan job to reorder them by hand and burn a DVD after that.

Is there a way to ask iMovie to just create 1 giant clip with the content of a tape? or any other way to sort the clips as they stands on the tape (import order will be fine)

Or, eventually, Is there another app that does the job?

Comment: Is your goal to just use the DVD as a backup medium (by copying the DV files onto an ISO file system on the disc) or to you want to create a real DVD playable on any DVD player?

Comment: I want to have a playable DVD. But, if i can have a video file with the content of the tape, i'll be able to make a playable DVD with iDVD for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to get a single large DV file imported from tape, depending on whether your constraint is budget or time:

1) [QuickTime Pro 7](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/) has a recording mode that can see DV devices. Yes, Apple still charges $29.99 for it, but the interface is simple and lets you record a long, single file. Just make sure the capture format in the app's preferences is set to 'Device Native' or something along those lines (I believe it wants to transcode to MPEG-4 by default).

2) [WhackedTV](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/WhackedTV) was a free sample application provided by Apple to developers to demonstrate video capture frameworks. The app seems to be gone from Apple's site but a [third-party mirror is available](http://www.epiphan.com/downloads/WhackedTV.zip). This app lets you add a DV video/audio source, configure its capture format, and record as long as you need to. I still use this app on a regular basis.

3) A final option is to script the standard QuickTime 7 player via AppleScript to open a video capture window, which it will allow you to do even if you haven't purchased Pro. Unfortunately, I don't have the original source code for this script, so you would have to open up AppleScript Editor and QT7's dictionary and work it out through trial and error.

Any of these recording approaches will yield a .dv file (or a DV file in a .mov container), either of which can be taken in by iDVD, a simpler DVD app like [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html), or by Handbrake if you wish to transcode to MPEG-4/H.264.

Comment: I have used the QT7 Device Native methodology mentioned above - it works well. Device Native is under Quality (New Movie, CMD-, to preferences, select the Recording tab). Also, be sure your recording drive is freshly formatted and one large partition, and depending on the age of your Mac, that there isn't any other USB or networks devices attached (be sure to turn off Time Machine too).

Once transferred, you can import into iMovie/iDVD to do you editing/DVD encryption

Comment: I've tried the QT7 : It works but since there are changes from time to time in the "recording format" on the tape, it stops importing at each change. I've also tried WhackedTV and I have till now "sounds problem" (sync problems) I've to try with some other import sound's prefs, I guess.

Comment: Broken Link for WhackedTV.  404 (not found)

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to take the video content from a mini-dvd and place it on a normal sized DVD, you can use HandBrake to do this. You will get a video file as an output, given a source disc.

If your goal is to re-burn onto a DVD as a playable DVD, then you may want to use DiskUtility to image the miniDVD to a DVD ISO file, then burn that DVD ISO to a blank DVD.

Comment: Sorry, but when I use HandBrake, the import feature opens a 'select file...' dialog box. The video recorder doesn't show up on my desktop. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: please refer to this guide:

http://www.macworld.com/article/1157590/how_to_rip_dvd_handbrake.html

Comment: Ok you read miniDVD intstead of MiniDV. It's a tape formart. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiniDV#Magnetic_tape